# Android bluetooth scan periodic advertising

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I am new to Android develop and bluetooth stuff so if my question sound stupid please forgive me, I am working on Nordic 52840 using their nrf connect sdk 2.0.0 example bluetooth periodic advertising, I want to scan my nordic device and receive the advertising data using android phone Android 10.0, I can find other device using my code such as some notebook,samsung TV etc, but can't find the nordic device I need.

```
package com.example.ble_scanner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTdevice=new ArrayList<>();
    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;
    ListView lvNewDevice;
    public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
    public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;

private boolean mScanning = false;
private Handler mHandler = null;

private Button btnScan = null;

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastreceiver1=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action =intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)){
            final int state=intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG,"STATE OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG,"TURNNING OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG,"STATE ON");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG,"TURNNING ON");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastreceiver2=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action =intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)){
            final int state=intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE,mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG,"DISCOVERABLE");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Discoverability Disable,Able to receive connection");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Discoverability Disable,unable to receive connection");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Connecting...");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Connected");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastreceiver3=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action =intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive:ACTION FOUND");
        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mBTdevice.add(device);
            Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: "+device.getName()+" : "+device.getAddress());
            mDeviceListAdapter=new DeviceListAdapter(context,R.layout.device_adapter_view,mBTdevice);
            lvNewDevice.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);

        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy called");
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvNewDevice=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevice);
    mBTdevice=new ArrayList<>();
    mBluetoothAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Button Btbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Btbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"enable disable button");
            enabledisableBT();
        }
    });
    Button discover=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    discover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            discoverenabledisable();
        }
    });
    Button scan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scanBTDevice();
        }
    });

}


public void enabledisableBT(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter==null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Does not have BT function");
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableBTIntent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);

        IntentFilter BTIntent=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver1,BTIntent);
    }
    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        IntentFilter BTIntent=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver1,BTIntent);
    }
}
public void discoverenabledisable(){
    Log.d(TAG,"make device discoverable for 300 second");

    Intent discoverableIntent= new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver2,intentFilter);
}
public void scanBTDevice(){
    Log.d(TAG,"Scan device");

    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG,"cancel scan");
        checkBTPermission();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoveryDeviceIntent =new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver3,discoveryDeviceIntent);
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        checkBTPermission();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter discoveryDeviceIntent =new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastreceiver3,discoveryDeviceIntent);
    }
}
private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
```

}
[my app find some bluetooth device but not the one i needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGguw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently searching for Bluetooth Classic devices but your nRF52840 is using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). These are both part of the Bluetooth standard but are not compatible. Please read the [BLE overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview) as well as the [find BLE devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices) page of the Android Developer Documentation.

BLE can be hard to handle for many developers and there are a lot of guides online to help you further than the Android documentation. I personaly had success using the [Making Android BLE work](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02) guide by Martijn van Welie.